# ANT Script: Regular expression to extract all string before last 2 slashes

Tags: ant

Full String: C:\Shrijeet\BW-AUTOMATION-PROJECT\Deploy\CheckedOutproject\TestMaven\testsrv-system\testsrv-esb\src\main\bw-testsrv-esb\deployment\bw-testsrv-esb.archive

I would like to capture only below ant property:

C:\Shrijeet\BW-AUTOMATION-PROJECT\Deploy\CheckedOutproject\TestMaven\testsrv-system\testsrv-esb\src\main\bw-testsrv-esb\

Please can you help with regular expression for this.I tried but i am not able to correctly extract it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer after some trials.
regexp="(.*\)(.*\)" will solve my purpose

```
<propertyregex property="app_project_path" override="true" input="${app_ear_archive}" regexp="(.*\\)(.*\\)" select="\1" />
```